# Aumentar la versión de mi aplicación de escritorio de manera automática, Vb .net

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net

Es posible que mi aplicación de escritorio(vb o C#) aumente de versión automáticamente cada vez que realice una compilación?

Comment: Hola, podrías aceptar las respuestas de las preguntas que has realizado? Acabo de ver que tienes algunas pendientes en http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/4779/avargasma Al aceptar una respuesta haces que el sitio mejore. Saludos :D

Comment: Si, si es posible.

Answer (score 2):

Una manera sencilla es modificar el fichero AssemblyInfo.vb.

Si comentas estas líneas:

```
'<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")> 
'<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")>
```

Y lo dejas así:

```
<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")>
```

Se te irán generando versionados incrementados.

Answer (score 1):

Existen extensiones que puedes agregar al VS para implementar el incremento del versionado automatico

[Automatic Versions](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dd8c5682-58a4-4c13-a0b4-9eadaba919fe)

[Auto Version Incrementer Gratis](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e30465a4-dab9-44ca-815b-b390ceeef6ab)

puedes descargar el .vsix de estos links o puedes buscarlo en el Extension Manager

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Una opción bastante sencilla es utilizar ClickOnce, puedes hacer un deployment completo muy facil a tus clientes, que por si misma ya incluye el manejo de versiones, y updates.

-> [How to use click once](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4BTLdIMYEY)